# What's the best way to handle something like a login page on top of Zend Framework? (And why does my implementation explode?)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-application

**EDIT:** Sorry for the large amount of code here; I'm not sure exactly what's going on so I included more to be safe.

I've currently got a login page which farms out to a central authentication service. I'd like to do a permissions check on the user. If the user is not logged in, I'd like to redirect them to the login page, and have the login page redirect them to do whatever action it was they were originally doing, running the access check again. If they don't have permission, I want to redirect them to an access denied page.

Here's what I've done so far:

Added this line to my `application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Cas_Controller_Action_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers/helpers"
```

Created the file `$/application/controllers/helpers/PermissionRequire.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * This class is used in order to require that a user have a given privilege before continuing.
 *
 * @copyright 2011 Case Western Reserve University, College of Arts and Sciences
 * @author Billy O'Neal III (bro4@case.edu)
 */

class Cas_Controller_Action_Helper_PermissionRequire extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Cleans up the supplied list of privileges. Strings are turned into the real privilege objects (Based on name),
     * privilege objects are left alone.
     *
     * @static
     * @param array|Privilege|string $privileges
     * @return array
     */
    private static function CleanPrivileges($privileges)
    {
        if (!is_array($privileges))
        {
            $privileges =
                    array
                    (
                        $privileges
                    );
        }
        $strings = array_filter($privileges, 'is_string');
        $objects = array_filter($privileges, function($o)
        {
            return $o instanceof Privilege;
        });
        $databaseObjects = PrivilegeQuery::create()->filterByName($strings)->find();
        return array_combine($objects, $databaseObjects);
    }

    /**
     * Generic implementation for checking whether a user can visit a page.
     * @param Privilege|string|array $privileges Any number of privileges which are required to access the given
     *                                           page. If ANY privilege is held by the user, access is allowed.
     * @param AccessControlList The acl which is being checked. Defaults to the application.
     */
    public function direct($privileges, $acl = null)
    {
        $privileges = self::CleanPrivileges($privileges);
        if ($acl === null)
        {
            $acl = AccessControlListQuery::getApplication();
        }
        $redirector = $this->getActionController()->getHelper('redirector');
        /** @var Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector $redirector */
        $redirector->setCode(307);
        if (Cas_Model_CurrentUser::IsLoggedIn() && (!Cas_Model_CurrentUser::AccessCheck($acl, $privileges)))
        {
            $redirector->gotoSimple('accessdenied', 'login');
        }
        else
        {
            $returnData = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Login');
            $returnData->params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $redirector->setGotoSimple('login', 'login');
            $redirector->redirectAndExit();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the LoginController:

```
<?php

/**
 * LoginController - Controls login access for users
 */

require_once 'CAS.php';

class LoginController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Logs in to the system, and redirects to the calling action.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        //Authenticate with Login.Case.Edu.
        phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, 'login.case.edu', 443, '/cas', false);
        phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
        phpCAS::forceAuthentication();

        $user = CaseIdUser::createFromLdap(phpCAS::getUser());
        Cas_Model_CurrentUser::SetCurrentUser($user->getSecurityIdentifier());

        $returnData = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Login');
        /** @var array $params */
        $redirector = $this->_helper->redirector;
        /** @var Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector $redirector */
        $redirector->setGotoRoute($returnData->params, 'default', true);
        $returnData->unsetAll();
        $redirector->redirectAndExit();
    }

    /**
     * Logs the user out of the system, and redirects them to the index page.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        Cas_Model_CurrentUser::Logout();
        $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute('index','index', 'default', true);
    }

    /**
     * Returns an access denied view.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function accessdeniedAction()
    {
        //Just display the view and punt.
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the login controller when it's preparing the URL to redirect the user to, it seems "params" is `null`. Also, this won't work when there's POST data to the controller calling `$this->_helper->permissionRequire(SOME PRIVILEGE)`.

Is there a better way of storing the entire state of a request, and coughing up a redirect which exactly matches that request?

P.S. Oh, and here's an example controller using that helper:

```
<?php

/**
 * Serves as the index page; does nothing but display views.
 */

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $renderer = $this->getHelper('ViewRenderer');
        /** @var $renderer Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer */
        if (Cas_Model_CurrentUser::IsLoggedIn())
        {
            $this->_helper->permissionRequire(Cas_Model_Privilege::GetLogin());
            $this->render('loggedin');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->render('loggedout');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you want to check something for every request, that code should be in your front controller plugin - http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372

Comment: @emaillenin: That is true; but I'm not trying to do this on every request. I want this to be a helper method because not all action controllers, and indeed, not all actions within an action controller, require the same permissions everywhere. The action controller itself needs to make that determination.

Comment: I think you have to check Zend_Acl & Zend_Auth components !

Comment: your point is agreed. but you cannot check for permissions in each of your action controllers. if you have your checkpermissions as a front controller plugin, it can receive the module/controller/action name in its request and based on predefined permissions for each action, perform appropriate actions (Zend_Acl does that)

Comment: @ArneRie: Zend_Acl cannot be persisted in the database. Therefore I was forced to implement it myself. @emaillenin: The permissions required for each action cannot be statically defined for each action. The action determines whether or not an activity is allowed based on arguments to the action. Example: Bob has delegate rights to Sally, but not to Bill. Bob tries to order something for Sally, and can do so because he has that delegate right. Bob tries to do the same for Bill, and gets redirected to the access denied page. Zend_Acl also doesn't handle grouping, which I needed.

Comment: ... continued ... I basically reimplemented NT's access control model on top of SQL. Regardless, the reason I'm doing this isn't the point of the question; being able to redirect the user perfectly back to the calling action (with the same parameters) is the point. How can I do that?

Comment: @ArnieRie: Oh, and also Zend_Auth doesn't work because I'm not providing the authentication; the CAS service is.

Comment: Don't use @return void, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061550/phpdoc-return-void-necessary

Comment: @Markus: PHPStorm puts it on there; and it's used for the auto completion feature. PHPDocumentor just ignores it.

Comment: @Billy: What does it do for auto completion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are so keen on saving the POST state of the request, and because I've been playing around with this same idea myself to for a long time, how about something like the following. It's still untested though, so I'ld love to hear the outcome of whether setting the saved request like this actually works as expected. (To lazy to test this at the moment, sorry).

In your config ini:

```
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Cas_Controller_Plugin_Authenticator"
```

Here's the plugin:

```
class Cas_Controller_Plugin_Authenticator
    extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeStartup( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request )
    {
        if( Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity() )
        {
            if( null !== $request->getParam( 'from-login', null ) && Zend_Session::namespaceIsset( 'referrer' ) )
            {
                $referrer = new Zend_Session_Namespace( 'referrer' );
                if( isset( $referrer->request ) && $referrer->request instanceof Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract )
                {
                    Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setRequest( $referrer->request );
                }
                Zend_Session::namespaceUnset( 'referrer' );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $referrer = new Zend_Session_Namespace( 'referrer' );
            $referrer->request = $this->getRequest();
            return $this->_redirector->gotoRoute(
                array(
                    'module' => 'default',
                    'controller' => 'user',
                    'action' => 'login'
                ),
                'default',
                true
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin should check on `routeStartup` whether the user is authenticated;

- If the user IS NOT: it saves the current request object in the session and redirects to the `UserController::loginAction()`. (see below)
- If the user IS: it retrieves the saved request object from the session (if available, AND if user has just logged in) and replaces the current request object in the frontController (which proxies to the router I should think).

All in all, if you want some more flexibility for determining what module/controller/action params need authentication and authorization (which I imagine you want) you probably want to move some of the checking to another hook than `routeStartup`: namely `routeShutdown`, `dispatchLoopStartup` or `preDispatch`. Because by then the action params should be known.  As an extra security measure you may also want to compare the action params (module/controller/action) of the original request and the replacing request to determine if your dealing with the correct saved request.

Furthermore, you may need to set `$request->setDispatched( false )` on the new request object, in some or all of the hooks. Not entirely sure though: see the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html).

And here is an example login controller:

```
class UserController
    extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if( $request->isPost() )
        {
            if( someAuthenticationProcessIsValid() )
            {
                if( Zend_Session::namespaceIsset( 'referrer' ) )
                {
                    $referrer = new Zend_Session_Namespace( 'referrer' );
                    if( isset( $referrer->request ) && $referrer->request instanceof Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract )
                    {
                        return $this->_redirector->gotoRoute(
                            array(
                                'module' => $referrer->request->getModuleName(),
                                'controller' => $referrer->request->getControllerName(),
                                'action' => $referrer->request->getActionName(),
                                'from-login' => '1'
                            ),
                            'default',
                            true
                        );
                    }   
                }

                // no referrer found, redirect to default page
                return $this->_redirector->gotoRoute(
                    array(
                        'module' => 'default',
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action' => 'index'
                    ),
                    'default',
                    true
                );
            }
        }

        // GET request or authentication failed, show login form again
    }
}
```

For security reasons, you might want to set a session variable with an expiration hop of 1 in stead of the 'from-login' querystring variable though.

Finally, having said all this; you might want to thoroughly think about whether you really want this behaviour in the first place. POST requests, as you of course know, generally inhibit sensitive state changing operations (creating, deleting, etc.). I'm not sure users generally expect this behaviour right after logging in (after their session had just expired). Also, you might want to think about possible scenarios where this can lead to unexpected behaviour for the application itself. I can't think of any specifics right now, but if I gave it more thought, I'm sure I could come up with some.

HTH

**EDIT**
Forgot to add the correct redirect actions after the login process

Answer (score 1):

When it's a GET request, it's pretty straightforward: On missing auth, save the request url in the session and redirect to login. After login, if there is a saved request url, send him there. For successful auth, but failed access privileges, send him right away to access-denied.

The sticky point is a POST request. Saving only the request url misses the data in the post. Even if you also save those params and the request type ('POST') in the session, is it possible for a post-login redirect to operate as a POST request? To me, that's the essence of the question.

One solution could be to do a post-login redirect to a transition page containing a form (with `method="post"`) with all the original post data stashed away in hidden fields. Then, run some on-load javascript that hides the submit button and submits the form. In the absence of javascript, it degrades - relatively - gracefully: the user simply has to click the submit button.

Would that work?

Comment: I don't think there is a general way of putting the data back into the page the user uses to redirect. That's why I put the data into the session....

Comment: What I mean is, I don't care what method I use to return to the calling controller, so long as that controller has a neat way of getting to those POST variables.

Comment: That's what this transition form achieves. On missing auth, save the url and the post data *into the session*. After login, redirect to this transition form and use the data saved in the session to populate hidden fields. On submit of this form - automated if there is javascript support - the original controller will receive all the data in a post, just like it expects. The only difference is that now the user is logged-in, so you can apply any additional ACL checks and process normally. See what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a coded answer, but something which may help. I faced a similar problem when I implemented using Zend_ACL and Zend_Auth using a MySQL back-end. I came across a few times where I needed a user who didn't normally have access to a controller action to be granted it for a situation. Zend have thought of this, and so you can use [Assertions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html) to allow access where access would normally have been denied.

The problem I then faced was, I set a login timeout limit - so if the user left the computer and someone came along they couldn't do anything as the system would be logged out.

The problem being if they had filled out a form *(there are some huge forms)* and taken more than the allowed login time, when they submitted the form, they would land at the login page - very annoying if it had taken 30 mins to complete the form. Hence I needed the user to be redirected to the action which accepted the original form, but somehow post the original data as a POST request. *[My original question on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069302/send-post-from-php-zend-framework-site)*

So how I have solved this, and maybe not the best solution but it works. *[Inspiration came from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309456/redirect-to-new-page-w-post-data-php-zend)*

When the user arrives at the login page check if its a **POST**

**Serialize** the **POST** data and place it in a session with the requested **URL**.

Once successfully auth'd **FORWARD** the request to the URL saved in the session.

Now in the correct place, check for any serialized data and un-serialize it setting $_POST to the data.

The reason this works for me is, when the user submits the login form, you check the users details, perform the actions you need to log them in, then forward them instead of redirecting them, this way the request is still a POST - so when you change the $_POST data to the original which you have un-serialized the page will work as normal, even checking `$this->getRequest()->isPost()`. 
*Where I do find a problem is, and I haven't tried tackling it yet, if the user presses the back button, they would get to the login form, which they aren't allowed to as they are now logged in so get a message advising they aren't allowed there, it would be better if they got back to the original form - so it ices over the login.*

If you think this will help, I can try and cut up some of the code I use to give an idea exactly how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted what I am using in my project to protect one controller based on whether the user is logged. The following code can be used to check for special permissions also while checking for login. If the user is not having appropriate privileges, redirect to error controller or display error views.

This code has example for what is asked in question - Keeping the current URL in param when redirecting to another controller and redirecting back to the same URL on success.

```
class ProtectedController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {

    if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
               //Show the content
       } else {
                $this->_redirect('user/login/?success=' . $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
            }
        }

    }
```

And the UserController

```
class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function loginAction() {
            $returnURL = $this->_getParam('success', '/');
            if (checkAuthenticity()) {
                $this->_redirect($returnURL);
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: This is broken for several reasons. First, the redirect call in "protected controller" is completely broken if you application isn't installed on the root of the webserver. Second, it can't handle POST data. Third, you would at least need to escape the URL you put into the generated link.

Comment: @Billy 1st and 3rd point agreed. what is it that it cant handle POST data?

Comment: When you redirect back to the calling controller action you don't preserve data POSTed there.