# How to keep all the POST information while redirecting in PHP?

Tags: php, post

```
header('Location: ' . $uri);
```

This will miss all the `$_POST` information.

Comment: How about `header("Location: $url", TRUE, 307)`?

Comment: @JefreySobreiraSantos Thank you for your awesome answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if u want to carry forward  your `POST` data to another pages ( except the `action` page) then use

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['post_data'] = $_POST;
```

Comment: If the script on the $uri expects the data to be put in $_POST this will not work.

Comment: If you control the script, you *could* change it to check both.

Answer (score 18):

Don't use $_SESSION as you have been suggested. Session data is shared with all other pages, including the ones open in other tabs. You may get unpredictable behaviour if you use the same trick in multiple places of your website.

An untested better code would be something like this.

```
session_start();
$data_id = md5( time().microtime().rand(0,100) );
$_SESSION["POSTDATA_$data_id"] = $_POST;
header('Location: ' . $uri."?data_id=$data_id");
```

In the next page you may retrieve the previous post like this

```
session_start();
$post = array();
$data_key = 'POSTDATA_'.$_GET['data_id'];
if ( !empty ( $_GET['data_id'] ) && !empty( $_SESSION[$data_key] ))
{ 
    $post = $_SESSION[$data_key];
    unset ( $_SESSION[$data_key] );
}
```

The code above is not tested, you may have to deal with some error before it works.

Comment: missing a  ) on second line ?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you **can't** redirect POST requests.

Either let your server proxy the request (i.e. make a cURL request to the other site) or create another form, fill it with hidden fields and submit it with Javascript/let the user click.

Alternatively, as @diEcho says, depending on what you're trying to do: sessions.

Comment: +1. More details in this approach appear here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189450/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-something-like-a-login-page-on-top-of-zend-framewor/5194436#5194436

Answer (score 1):

If you perform a redirect the post will be lost and a GET will occur.

You could save your POST in a SESSION or encode it in the GET (as query string)

Answer (score 1):

You could save the post data in the session, redirect, and then retrieve it back from the session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['POSTDATA'] = $_POST;
header('Location: ' . $uri);
```

Then in the PHP file for the new location, retrieve the post data like this:

```
$_POST = $_SESSION['POSTDATA'];
```

Answer (score -2):

I do use my own simple method.

Just think very logical! For example if you use a text attribute which you want to keep the value of, you can use:

```
<?php $textvalue = $_POST['textname']; ?>
<input type="text" name="textname" value="<?php echo $textvalue; ?>" />

<br />

//And if you want to use this method for a radio button, you can use:
<?php if(isset($_POST['radio1']){
  $selected = "selected";
}  ?>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" <?php echo $selected; ?> />
```

Comment: This answer is wrong and short-sighted. It is not worth the trouble to edit it, because it makes no sense.