# dynamically add fields to HTML form, send data AND remember added fields and values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following problem:

I want to add textfields to my html form, send them to my script and than redirect back AND have the number of fields and their values shown.

Adding the fields via jQuery is working fine, but I can't store the values later on, because it's done via adding DIVs and they're having the same name.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Here's the code in my index.php and in my action.php

index.php

```php
    <?php
    session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 3600,
    ]);
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
     <!-- HTML5 -->
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
     <!-- HTML 4.x -->
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css' integrity='sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w' crossorigin='anonymous'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='style/style.css'>
     <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <title>
    myDrop2
    </title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    function showLoadingMessage() {
      document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';
      var message = document.createElement('div');
      message.innerHTML = '<center><h1>Wird gearbeitet, bitte warten!</h1></center>';
      document.body.appendChild(message);
    }
    function checkRemove() {
        if ($('div.d1_drops').length == 1) {
            $('#remove').hide();
        } else {
            $('#remove').show();
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        checkRemove()
        $('#add').click(function() {
            $('div.d1_drops:last').after($('div.d1_drops:first').clone());
            $('div.d2_drops:last').after($('div.d2_drops:first').clone());
            checkRemove();
        });
        $('#remove').click(function() {
            $('div.d1_drops:last').remove();
            $('div.d2_drops:last').remove();
            checkRemove();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <center>
    <div id='header'>
       <b>myDrop2</b>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id='content'>
    <br>
    <button id='add'>[ + ]</button>
    <button id='remove'>[ - ]</button>
    <form action=scripts/action.php class='pure-form pure-form-aligned' onsubmit='showLoadingMessage();' method='post'>
    <!-- <form action=scripts/action.php class='pure-form pure-form-aligned' onsubmit='showLoadingMessage();' method='post'> -->
    <div id='settings1'>
    <br>
      Belichtung starten
      <br><br>
      <label>Warten (ms) <input name='firstwait' type='number'></label>
    </div>
    <div id='ventile'>
    <div id='ventil1'>
       <input type='radio' id='v1' name='ventile' value='1' checked='checked'>
       <label for='v1'><h2>1 Ventil</h2></label>
       <br><br>
       <div class='d1_drops'>
      <label>Tropfen 1 Dauer (ms) <input name='d1_drop[]' type='number'></label>
      <br><br>
      <label>Warten (ms) <input name='d1_wait[]' type='number'></label>
       <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='ventil2'>
       <input type='radio' id='v2' name='ventile' value='2'>
       <label for='v2'><h2>2 Ventile</h2></label>
       <br><br>
       <div class='d2_drops'>
      <label>Tropfen 1 Dauer (ms) <input name='d2_drop[]' type='number'></label>
      <br><br>
      <label>Warten (ms) <input name='d2_wait[]' type='number'></label>
      <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id='settings2'>
      Blitzen
      <br><br>
      <label>Warten (ms) <input name='lastwait' type='number'></label>
      <br><br>
      Belichtung stoppen
      <br><br>
    </div>
    <div id='run'>
      <button type='submit'>ausführen</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

action.php

```php
    <?php
    session_start();
    include ('../conf.php');
    $d1_array_drop = $_POST['d1_drop'];
    $d1_array_wait = $_POST['d1_wait'];
    $d2_array_drop = $_POST['d2_drop'];
    $d2_array_wait = $_POST['d2_wait'];
        (...) do stuff with the data (..)
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionstorage or localstorage to remember values,if you want to output values from php ,first store them in session|files|db after redirecting , you can just output the values to js

```
<?php
$data=$_SESSION["data"];
?><script>
var data=<?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, could you provide me with an example?

Comment: This will help you in proper way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204055/how-to-keep-all-the-post-information-while-redirecting-in-php) ,if redirected page is on different server better put a get request in redirect url or some other data transfer methos

Comment: Thank you very much, I glanced at the other thread, and see a good way to realise my idea.

Comment: no problem =) Would appreciate an upvote from you too ;)