# Redirect saving POST parameters using HTTP

Tags: java, http, post, redirect

I have 2 web-pages.

So, 1st page takes some POST parameters, and then process it. I want to redirect this query(with all POST params) to my own 2nd page, if  parameter "appId" = "myApp";

In start of 1st page I make next:

```
    if (getParameter("id") == "myApp") 
    {
        request.setHttpHeader("")  - ??? WHAT MUST BE HERE? WHICH HEADERS?
    }
```

P.S. I need only HTTP solution, using native (java) methods (like forward and redirect) don't help me.

Thanks.

Comment: [try it](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-redirect-a-request-using-servlet.html)

Comment: That example is not at all handling a post request.

Comment: you handle the POST request by implement as same as the example in the doPost method

Comment: But that explains sendRedirect where as using RequestDispatcher will be a better approach.

Comment: @punny, thankyou, but I think that code:



`res.setStatus(res.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
 res.setHeader("Location", site);`



== 

`res.sendRedirect("url");` not so?

Answer (score 1):

You have to user RequestDispatcher.forward. Here is an example.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ForwardServlet extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        /*
         * You can do any processing here. 
         * We will simply output the value of name parameter on server console.
         * 
         */
        System.out.println(name);
        String destination = "/DestinationServlet";

        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: @MyTitle said "using native (java) methods (like forward and redirect) don't help me." in the last line of this question

Comment: @Ravindra Gullapalli, yes, thanks. I know that exist this solution. But my page in another context (so I can't use method "forward"). Also I know that I can forward request from one context to another, but I dont want to make so more changes in 1st JSP page (because its written not by me). Also I can't use "sendRedirect" method (because I need POST request).

Comment: @MyTitle Then you can do one thing. Render HTML code using ServletOutputStream and create a invisible form with a simple message "Processing your request". Then submit that form using java script.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for can't be done with pure HTTP. You can only redirect GETs with HTTP. See this answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/1310897/116509