# php, how to send a manual post within the zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, post, get

im not sure if the question was framed correctly, but here is my situation:

i have two actions:  `indexAction` and `searchAction`

a third action looks something like this:

```
public function customsearchAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isPost()){

        $category = $request->getParam('select_category');
        $searchString   = $request->getParam('header_search_form');

        if($category == 'index'){
            $this->_redirector->gotoSimple('index', 'index', null,
                                   array('term' => $searchString )
                                   );
        }
        if($category == 'search'){
            $this->_redirector->gotoSimple('search', 'index', null,
                                   array('term' => $searchString )
                                   );
        }
    }
}
```

this is fine and dandy, the only problem is that the redirect adds the `term` as a get string instead of a post like i need it.

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to new page w/ POST data (PHP/Zend)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309456/redirect-to-new-page-w-post-data-php-zend)

Comment: yes, it looks like is a duplicate, i saw that post but i wasn't sure that that example it takes any params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser redirect will always add term to GET for next request to process. What you can do here is use ZF MVC internal redirect using 'forward' .

```
$this->_forward('search','index',null,array('term' => $searchString ));
```

Inside your searchAction

```
$searchString = $this->_getParam('term');
```

Comment: Thanks, just saved me from having to read the dreaded Zend docs.