# Zend Framework $this->_forward to send POST/GET parameters

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, post

Is it possible to send POST/GET parameters to in a controller using

```
$this->_forward("/url/here");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php, how to send a manual post within the zend framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611954/php-how-to-send-a-manual-post-within-the-zend-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function fooAction()
{
    // forward to another action in the current controller and module:
    $this->_forward('bar', null, null, array('baz' => 'bogus'));
}

public function barAction()
{
    // forward to an action in another controller:
    // FooController::bazAction(),
    // in the current module:
    $this->_forward('baz', 'foo', null, array('baz' => 'bogus'));
}

public function bazAction()
{
    // forward to an action in another controller in another module,
    // Foo_BarController::bazAction():
    $this->_forward('baz', 'bar', 'foo', array('baz' => 'bogus'));
}
```

according to the manual , you can send parameters with an array , should be the last argument.

Comment: GET. You can't send POST request. (unless you submit a form or using Zend_Http_Client)