# Data attached to POST request is gone during redirection to GET with CURL

Tags: linux, redirect, curl

I wrote followed command to send POST with JSON data to server. The server must redirect my request and send GET with the same data:

```
curl  -L -i -XPOST \
     -d 'id=105' \
     -d 'json={"orderBy":0,"maxResults":50}'  http://mysite.com/ctlClient/
```

I get response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2013 13:12:08 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1hn0g8d7gtfl4nghjvab63btmk2; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
location: http://mysite.com/fwf/online/
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2013 13:12:08 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=16akc7kdcoet71ipjflk9o9cnm5; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

From access-log I see:

```
 "POST /ctlClient/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)"
 "GET /fwf/online/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)"
```

So far so good,

The problem is that `GET` doesn't  receives my data added to post. Sounds like during redirect my data dismissed somehow. **From Android client it works, therefore its not Server side problem.**

**What I need to do to pass POST data to GET request?**

Thank you very much,

**[EDIT]**

@nif offerd to upgrade `CURL`, i did ,  to 7.28.0.

Still get the same problem

**[INFO]**

1st time i go to `http://mysite.com/ctlClient/index.php` where:

```
 case 105: // id=105
        session_unset();
        session_start();
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){$_SESSION[$key] = $value;}
        ctlGotoSameDomain("/fwf/online/"); // <- aka redirect
        return true;
```

after redirect i go to `/fwf/online/index.php` and there my request is empty:

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->json = isset($_SESSION['json']) ? $_SESSION['json'] : null;
        msqLogFile("fwf/post", Array('post' => 'Request: '.$this->json));

    }
```

`http://mysite.com/ctlClient/index.php` get 2 parameters properly: `id` and `json`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309456/redirect-to-new-page-w-post-data-php-zend

Comment: well, i need curl syntax but not PHP. thanks

Answer (score 9):

From [curl's manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

> When  curl  follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request using the same unmodified method.

**Edit**

I did some research and found out, that it might be a problem with your curl version. Newer version will honour the `-XPOST` option and will `POST` to the redirected location as well. But older versions had an own option for this, i.e. `--post301` and `--post302`. According to their manpage:

> --post301
> Tells curl to respect RFC 2616/10.3.2 and not convert POST requests into GET
> requests when following a 301 redirection. The non-RFC behaviour is ubiquitous
> in web browsers, so curl does the conversion by default to maintain
> consistency. However, a server may require a POST to remain a POST after such
> a redirection. This option is meaningful only when using -L, --location
> (Added in 7.17.1)
>
> --post302
> Tells curl to respect RFC 2616/10.3.2 and not convert POST requests into GET
> requests when following a 302 redirection. The non-RFC behaviour is ubiquitous
> in web browsers, so curl does the conversion by default to maintain
> consistency. However, a server may require a POST to remain a POST after such
> a redirection. This option is meaningful only when using -L, --location
> (Added in 7.19.1)

**References:**

- [Following redirects with curl](http://www.recursion.org/2011/11/18/following-redirects-with-curl)
- [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Strange. From Android it work's. Redirects with 302 and pass data

Comment: That's truly strange. In the first reference I posted, it is mentioned that setting `-XPOST` will work around this issue. But it seems that this doesn't always work, as the OP used the flag but the method changed. Maybe it works for some curl versions only.

Comment: I have `curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @MaximShoustin: After taking a quick look at the source code of 7.15.5, I can't see a way to override the behaviour. You should upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: :( ver 7.28.0 doesn't work also, after POST, GET redirect is empty

Comment: 7.28.0 should have the `--post301` and `--post302` options. Have you tried them?

Comment: Yes, means do not switch to GET after redirect, but after switch i NEED `GET`

Comment: see my additional info, the request is empty. I put 1st time data to session, but after redirect it empty

Answer (score 1):

I need to add `-b` to my script to enable the cookies. CURL by default doesn't use them and this issue caused to session ID change. Therefore no data transferred.

```
curl -b -L -i -X POST \
 -d 'id=105' \
 -d 'json={"orderBy":0,"maxResults":50}'  http://mysite.com/ctlClient/
```

Now its working