# Zend Framework forward request with post http method

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, post

Using Zend Framework 1.7. Is possible to forward a request with `POST` method?
Something like this:

```
$this->_forward('action','controller','module',array('method'=>'POST'));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309456/redirect-to-new-page-w-post-data-php-zend

Comment: a forward don't ``redirect`` the browser to a new location and lose all the ``post`` data, with a ``forward`` in zend you point internal the current request to new action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, Try using following:

```
$this->_request->setPost(array('param_name' => $paramValue));
$this->_forward('actionName', 'controller', 'module');
```