# Zend form validation fails when setAction is used

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to validate form and if validation passes it has to be submitted  to connectTracking Action.

At present form gets submitted to connectTracking action before it passes validation.

Controller:

```
public function easyAction(){
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $user_id = $this->_helper->Utilities->getCurrentUserId();

    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $form       = new Application_Form_easy();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Submit');
        $this->view->form = $form;  
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ( ($this->getRequest()->getPost('easyform', false)) &&  ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) ) { 
            $username = $form->getValue('username');                
            $password = $form->getValue('password');
            $releasedata = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
        }
    }
}
```

/application/forms/easy.php

```
class Application_Form_easy extends Zend_Form {
    public function init() {
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setName('easyform');
        $this->setAction('/index.php/releases/connectTracking'); # Submitting to different action

        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $username->setLabel('Username * :')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Please enter Username'));

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $password->setLabel('Password * :')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Please enter password '));

                $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
                $submit->setAttrib('id', 'easyform');
                $submit->setAttrib('name', 'easyform');
                $this->addElements(array($username, $password, $submit));
    }
}
```

Could you please let me know how shall I validate the form and then submit to action

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `isValid` is the method to validate a form:

```
$form = new Application_Form_easy();
$formData = $this->_request->getPost();
if($form->isValid($formData)){
 //Form is valid, do your stuff
} else {
 //Form is not valid re-populate data
 $form->populate($formData);
}
```

In your case you are setting the form action this one `/index.php/releases/connectTracking` and you have written your validation code in `easyAction` which is wrong.
you have two ways here to achieve your requirement;

1) Set action of your form this `/controllerName/easy` and validate your form in `easyAction` (which you are doing right now) and if form is valid then redirect control to  `releases/connectTracking` action.

2) Another way is to write your validation code in `releases/connectTracking` Action and if form is not valid then redirect control again to `easy` Action with all the `POST` data to re-populate the form. And if form is valid then continue your stuff at `releases/connectTracking` action.

E.g. for first solution:

Controller:

```
public function easyAction(){
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $user_id = $this->_helper->Utilities->getCurrentUserId();

    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $form       = new Application_Form_easy();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Submit');
        $this->view->form = $form;  
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($form->isValid($formData)) { 
            $username = $form->getValue('username');                
            $password = $form->getValue('password');
            $releasedata = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
            //Form is valid, hence forward controller to another action with formData
            $this->_request->setPost(array('formData' => $formData));
            //Write actual module name in the below line
            $this->_forward('connectTracking', 'releases', 'moduleName');
            //$this->_redirect('/releases/connectTracking');
        } else {
          $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
}
```

Form:

```
class Application_Form_easy extends Zend_Form {
    public function init() {
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setName('easyform');
        //Write actual name of your controller here
        $this->setAction('/controllerName/easy'); # Submitting to same action

        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $username->setLabel('Username * :')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Please enter Username'));

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $password->setLabel('Password * :')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Please enter password '));

                $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
                $submit->setAttrib('id', 'easyform');
                $submit->setAttrib('name', 'easyform');
                $this->addElements(array($username, $password, $submit));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I need form data in connectTracking to process, so I will try the second solution

Comment: If you want formData in another action using first solution then you can easily post it before redirection in this way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954155/zend-framework-forward-request-with-post-http-method/24956070#24956070

Comment: In the above mentioned option if I redirect after validation I will not be able to get username and password data in connectTracking, I suppose.

Comment: To send form data to another action you need to use `_forward` instead of redirect. Refer edited code. In another action use `$formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();` to get `POST` data.